# Can I get the full Python3 Pandas package on Raspbian/Ubuntu?

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to port over a Python scraper I created on my mac to a raspberry pi, but I'm running into a few issues installing the required dependencies. I've used `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas` to install Pandas, but when I run my program I get an error saying "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'", which seems to indicate that the version of Pandas I've installed doesn't include this function.

I suspect that this version of Pandas, `pandas==0.23.3+dfsg`, isn't as built-out as the typical Pandas install for, say, a mac. Is there any way I can get this working by installing a different Pandas package?

Comment: [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) was introduced with v0.25.0 (see the docs).

Comment: I’ve tried to update my ‘python3-pandas’ package, but 0.23.3 seems to be the most up-to-date version available from my terminal. Could this be an issues with the version for Raspbian not being up to date?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Raspbian - but can you not install pandas via pip?

Comment: No, unfortunately you have to use the `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas` command to install on Linux, and this gives me the most recent version of 0.23.3 even if I force an update. I'm not sure how I can get the most recent version on Raspbian.